# auto scroll when reach end/top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to find a script which autoscroll the page up/down when the mouse coursor reach to the the top/bottom of the screen, and keep scroll until the user move out from the borders which count as end of screen.
I found some scripts but none of them really make it as it should.
anyone knows something that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine those 2 plugins:

1 To toggle the event : http://scrollmagic.io/

2 To autoscroll : http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/